# Slideshow transition between the pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, transition

How do I make some nice slow transition between the pictures in this slideshow?

```js
var slide = document.getElementById('slide');
var right_button = document.getElementById('arrow_right');
var left_button = document.getElementById('arrow_left');
var circle1 = document.getElementById('circle1');
var circle2 = document.getElementById('circle2');
var circle3 = document.getElementById('circle3');
var circle4 = document.getElementById('circle4');

var slike = ["slike/slide_1.png", "slike/slide_2.jpg", "slike/slide_3.jpg", "slike/slide_4.jpg"];

counter = 0;

right_button.onclick = function() {
    if (counter + 1 >= slike.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        counter++;
    }
    picChange(counter);
}

left_button.onclick = function() {
    if (counter <= 0) {
        counter = slike.length -1;
    }
    else {
        counter--;
    }
    picChange(counter);
}

function picChange(counter) {

    circle1.src = "slike/circle.png";
    circle2.src = "slike/circle.png";
    circle3.src = "slike/circle.png";
    circle4.src = "slike/circle.png";

    if (counter == 0) {
        slide.src = "slike/slide_1.png";
        circle1.src = "slike/active.png";
    }

    else if (counter == 1) {
        slide.src = "slike/slide_2.jpg";
        circle2.src = "slike/active.png";
    }

    else if (counter == 2) {
        slide.src = "slike/slide_3.jpg";
        circle3.src = "slike/active.png";
    }

    else {
        slide.src = "slike/slide_4.jpg";
        circle4.src = "slike/active.png";
    }

}
```

```html
<img src="slike/arrow_left.png" id="arrow_left">
<img src="slike/arrow_right.png" id="arrow_right">
<img src="slike/slide_1.png" id="slide">
<div id="circles">
    <img src="slike/active.png" id="circle1">
    <img src="slike/circle.png" id="circle2">
    <img src="slike/circle.png" id="circle3">
    <img src="slike/circle.png" id="circle4">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use CSS transitions or Javascript, however I'd stongly suggest jQuery as it's much simpler for these types of tasks. Have you even attempted this task yourself before you ask for help? Your code seems incomplete, is there more to it?

Comment: i cant use jquery, i believe its simpler though. Trust me ive been trying, for more than hour now :D i just have no idea how to do it... i'm doing this stuff for the first time..